# Kerberos SSO authentication in browser in windows

Tags: windows, dns, single-sign-on, kerberos

In a company network there is a web page, which uses kerberos single sign on. I am connecting to this network via VPN.

When using Mac, I can just write in the console kinit username@REALM.LOCAL, I get the ticket and after this I can open the web page in a browser and it works.

The other story happens on windows. I have my PC, I don't want it to become a member of the company domain. Via MIT Kerberos Client I can get a kerberos ticket, but of course no browser is aware of its existence.

Is there a way to feed this ticket to a browser on windows?

Answer (score 0):

Safari is very friendly, it will give your kerberos tickets to anybody. IE and firefox need to be configured to do this and I'm not sure if they will have access to the kerberos tickets unless your windows box is in the AD domain.

Basically, you need to configure your browser to support SPNEGO. With firefox, you need to tweak some variables in `about:config` See

http://www.microhowto.info/howto/configure_firefox_to_authenticate_using_spnego_and_kerberos.html

for the exact details. IE is a whole lot trickier.